# pgfplots: Centering a row in legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

For the following MWE, I would like to:

1. center the legend image of the long entry with its text,
2. expand the legend box to encompass its entries,
3. and center the second row of entries with respect to the legend width.

.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
    at={([yshift=30pt]0.5,1)},anchor=north,
    text width=1in,
    cells={align=left},
    minimum height=2mm
},
legend columns=3,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot [red,      line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {x};
\addlegendentry{$x$}
%
\addplot [black,    line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {(x-5)^2};
\addlegendentry{$(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [yellow,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-(x-5)^2}; \addlegendentry{$10-(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [orange,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-x};
\addlegendentry{$10-x$}
%
\addplot [green,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {5};
\addlegendentry{long long long long long entry}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer that addresses the first two or your wishes.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
    at={([yshift=30pt]0.5,1)},anchor=north,
    text width=1in,
    cells={align=left},
    minimum height=2mm
},
legend columns=3,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot [red,      line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {x};
\addlegendentry{$x$}
%
\addplot [black,    line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {(x-5)^2};
\addlegendentry{$(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [yellow,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-(x-5)^2}; \addlegendentry{$10-(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [orange,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-x};
\addlegendentry{$10-x$}
%
\addplot [green,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {5};
\addlegendentry{\begin{minipage}[b]{1in}
long long long
long long entry\end{minipage}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did not even attempt to solve the third issue because I think that the outcome does not look good, but this is only my personal opinion. Alternatively, I would probably use

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
    at={([yshift=30pt]0.5,1)},anchor=north,
    text width=1in,
    cells={align=left},
    minimum height=2mm
},
legend columns=3,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot [red,      line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {x};
\addlegendentry{$x$}
%
\addplot [black,    line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {(x-5)^2};
\addlegendentry{$(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [yellow,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-(x-5)^2}; \addlegendentry{$10-(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [orange,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-x};
\addlegendentry{$10-x$}
%
\addplot [green,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {5};
\addlegendentry{\begin{minipage}[b]{3in}
long long long
long long entry\end{minipage}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which IMHO looks good enough.

Comment: Your personal suggestion looks really nice. However, if I have another entry, how can I put it in the next (third) row considering your approach?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The proposal has two parts. If you have a sixth entry, just take the first proposal with the narrow(er) minipage.

Comment: I would be grateful if you don't mind explaining me something. When I try to make the entries as close to each other as possible by setting `/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0cm}`, the result looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/MQ9go). What do I miss here?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Most likely I do not understand your question. What precisely do you want to achieve? To understand what column sep does, just set it to a negative value and see what happens. Does setting `text width=0.7in,` in `legend style` give you what you want?